# Google Icon Font Two Tone not displaying on IOS

Tags: html, css, ios, google-font-api

I use the Material Icon Font Two Tone on my website, that display correctly on all device, except on IOS phones. 90% of the icons don't display.

The website is : https://axelor.com/

[The desk version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25jeN.png)

[The mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLH9a.png)

I tested with linked font and self-hosted font, but nothing change. I don't know what can I do more.